# Unable to install GMP in centOS

Tags: php, centos, gmp

I'm trying to install GMP Library (https://gmplib.org/) on my centOS server, but there's no luck.

I run this command :-

```
./configure
```

And it gives me this result :-

```
[root@centos-512mb-ams3-01 gmp-4.2.2]# ./configure
checking build system type... pentium3-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... pentium3-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=32
checking compiler gcc -m32 -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler gcc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... yes
checking compiler gcc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer has sizeof(long)==4... no
checking compiler icc -no-gcc ... no
checking whether cc is gcc... yes
checking compiler cc -m32 -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... no
checking compiler cc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer ... yes
checking compiler cc -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer has sizeof(long)==4... no
configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
[root@centos-512mb-ams3-01 gmp-4.2.2]#
```

I've tried all possible solutions. What is wrong here?

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using?

Comment: @JuliePelletier
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install it with the system's installer:

```
yum install php-gmp
```

Comment: i literally spent hours trying to find a solution for it. Do you know how I can install it for localhost use (Using WAMP). Edit :- It says I can accept your answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: In such application bundles, there is generally a simple way to access the php.ini which probably includes it commented out, but if not, just post another question for it.

Comment: `extension=php_gmp.dll` my php.ini has it uncommented.