# Install GMP on CentOS

Tags: centos, gmp

I've tried to install GMP on CentOS and this error appears:

```
yumdownloader --source gmp
Enabling mysql-tools-community-source repository
Enabling mysql-connectors-community-source repository
Enabling mysql56-community-source repository
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * epel: nl.mirror.babylon.network
 * epel-source: nl.mirror.babylon.network
 * extras: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
 * updates: centos.mirrors.ovh.net
No source RPM found for gmp-4.3.1-10.el6.x86_64
No source RPM found for gmp-4.3.1-10.el6.i686
Nothing to download
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Why are you trying to get the sources (of an antique version) instead of a binary package? If you really want sources, you might as well get recent ones directly from gmplib.org.

Comment: please note that is question was answered in the next url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190892/unable-to-install-gmp-in-centos

Answer (score 14):

How to install GMP : # `yum install gmp-devel`

Comment: @Paulo Monteiro, you can get the source src.rpm from Redhat : ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/gmp-4.3.1-10.el6.src.rpm . The same package is also available from the CentOS vault http://vault.centos.org/6.8/os/Source/SPackages/