# gmp is missing while configuring building gdb from source

Tags: gdb, gmp

I am trying to build gdb from source, which version is 11.1.
I have configured the GMP including path, but the configure script still report an error.

```
configure: error: GMP is missing or unusable
```

I copied the config log.

```
configure:10433: checking for libgmp
configure:10453: gcc -o conftest -g -O2      conftest.c -lncurses -lm -ldl  -lgmp >&5
conftest.c:53:17: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
```

My configure command is something like below.

```
configure --prefix=/home/xxx/ins/gdb_11 --with-gmp-include=/home/xxx/ins/gmp-6.2.1/include --with-gmp-lib=/home/xxx/ins/gmp-6.2.1/lib
```

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at GDB's configure script, I think the problem is that GDB is not picking up the --with-gmp-include and --with-gmp-lib configure flags.  These flags are handled in the toplevel configure script and made available to each sub-component (GDB, binutils, ld, etc) through the environment, and it looks like GDB doesn't pick these up.

The easiest way to move forward will be to override CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS at configure time, like:

```
configure CFLAGS="-I/gmp/include/path -L/gmp/lib/path" CXXFLAGS="-I/gmp/include/path -L/gmp/lib/path"
```

--- Later Edit ---

Though the technique in this answer will work, the correct answer is given by jiang da.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have libgmp-dev installed

My OS is ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-11.2.tar.gz
tar -xvzf gdb-11.2.tar.gz
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Once you installed GDB, you can print GDB version to test whether it is installed correctly.
`gdb --version`
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Msc.png)

Comment: If you're on centos: `yum install gmp-devel` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210582/install-gmp-on-centos

Answer (score 5):

You can use gdb's configure option:

```
  --with-libgmp-prefix="path to gmp"
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to share my experience how I solved this. No `sudo` on the server.
First, download `GMP` sources from the site (its certificate is expired now). I used `wget --no-check-certificate "https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz"`. To extract `tar -xf gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz`; in its directory `./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local`, `make`, `make install`, `make check` (installer politely asked, for some reason `check` target executed only after `install`).
Last operations with extracted `gdb` sources: in gdb directory `./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local`, `make`, `make install`. No `gmp` errors encountered.

Comment: Works well on my server without sudo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`config.log` files really help to understand your issue better.

In your case under `gdb/config.log` you'd find the error and command that generated it: `/.../gdb-x.y/gdb/configure`. If you go to the file you'll see it expects `--with-libgmp-prefix` and `--with-mpfr-prefix` flags. That's a [known gdb peculiarity](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/gdb/2022-March/049957.html).

You should pass these flags to the top-level configure along with `--with-gmp`, `--with-mpfr` etc. flags that you were passing as jiang da suggested. The actual build for me however was still failing with:

```
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpfr/4.2.0-p12' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If this happens, check the Makefile under `your_build_directory/gdb`, specifically what `LIBGMP` and `LIBMPFR` got resolved to. For me they were auto-configured to point to the directory and not the actual lib file, so I had to change:

```
LIBGMP=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1_1
LIBMPFR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpfr/4.2.0-p12
```

to

```
LIBGMP=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1_1/lib/libgmp.a
LIBMPFR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpfr/4.2.0-p12/lib/libmpfr.a
```

After which `make all-gdb` finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Following commands would work to install GDB along with its source codes -

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-<version>.tar.gz
tar -zxvf gdb-<version>.tar.gz

./configure --enable-debug
```

if configure showing error - configure: error: Building GDB requires GMP 4.2+, and MPFR 3.1.0+

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev
sudo dnf install gmp-devel mpfr-devel

./configure --enable-debug --datadir=/data-directory CFLAGS="-I/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib" LIBS="-lmpfr -lgmp"

make CFLAGS="-ggdb" CXXFLAGS="-ggdb"
```